# Why use of session name and session id in the get variables does not work?

Tags: php, session, get, file-get-contents

I have the following code:

```
$location .= 'red=no&'.session_name() . "=". session_id();
$content = file_get_contents($location);
echo $content;
```

If I run it, noting is displayed in my browser. However, if I modify it in the following way:

```
$location .= 'red=no';
$content = file_get_contents($location);
echo $content;
```

everything works fine (I see the content in my browser).

What is also strange, if I display the value of the $location variable from the first example (url) and manually paste it in the address line of my browser, I do see the content. So, my browser is able to use this URL and `file_get_contents` not.

Does anybody know how it can be explained?

Comment: what do `echo session_name();` and `echo session_id();` print out? Are you instantiating a session with `session_start();` somewhere?

Comment: Session name: whatever, session id: c8ec2afe8bb7388175f2065f1cb0c868

Comment: Yes, in the very beginning I have `session_start`

Answer (score 0):

this doesn't make sense. if the file is remote, and $location is a url, then what i think is happening is that the remote server doesn't take session id's via $_GET (or it rejects the one it's given by your server when your server makes it's request, or somesuch).

if the file is local, then the problem is that you've apparently got a file named **red=no&whatever=c8ec2afe8bb7388175f2065f1cb0c868**. actually, in this case i suspect the file may be named **red=no**. if not, the ampersand is throwing things off. escape it and you're ok.

or don't use such ghastly filenames.

Comment: The code that I have given is located in `en.example.org/index.php`. From the code, that I gave you can see only the part of the $location. The value of the location is: `example.org/index.php?red=no&whatever=c8ec...`. You say that the server probably do not accept sessions through get variables, but why then it works when I put the location in the address line?

Comment: does it work when you clear your browser's cookies? or better yet make the request in another browser?

Comment: what you're doing (asking one http client to make a request using a session that's given to another http client) is known as session spoofing. `example.org` is not going to let this work.